# How do you tell ktlint in android to exclude specific paths in the project?

Tags: android, ktlint

Currently when I want to format my code, I run this in the terminal in my android studio directory

https://github.com/pinterest/ktlint

```
./gradlew ktlintFormat
```

This command works great, but recently I added some folders into my project and the code in there is being checked by the ktlintFormat command. I wish to exclude those folders from being checked. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
ktlint {
    filter {
        exclude("**/generated/**")
        include("**/kotlin/**")
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work with JLLeitschuh/ktlint-gradle. See more here: https://github.com/JLLeitschuh/ktlint-gradle/issues/266.